# Access 2010 - Form navigation leads to Paramater Value Input dialogue - How do I stop this?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-office

In my Access 2010 database, I have an admin navigate to a form where they can add new users to the records. Upon clicking the button to navigate toward the new form, a dialogue box appears (see picture below).

[image: Dialogue Box]

When the field is left blank, an error occurs because the next command, `RecordsGoToNew`, is invalid. This field is unnecessary for what I am trying to accomplish (navigate to a different screen). Below are my macro's for the button, which I believe to be the cause of the issue.

[image: Macros for the button being pressed.]

Comment: It looks like it's looking for a field named `Last` or `Old.Last`.. You could delete it from your Form if you don't need it. I would also check for any queries (more likely than VBA) or VBA (doubtful, but check) if you're not confident this is the source.

Comment: It is possible the table that the form reads from has changed and the field `old.last` no longer exists.  The form is trying to read that field, but it finds nothing, so it is asking the user to input the value.